# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop

I keep getting the same error in my for loop (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable ), and I don't know what's my mistake. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import random

def compte(l,v):
    nbreOccurences = 0
    for i in l:
        if (i == v):
            nbreOccurences = nbreOccurences + 1
    return nbreOccurences

N = 100
            
l3 = []
for i in range(N):
    v = random.randrange(1,N+1)
    l3.append(v)

print(l3)
print(compte(13,3))
```

Comment: `compte(13,3)` Did you mean `compte(l3,3)` ? ie the list variable `l3`, not the integer literal `13`

Answer (score 1):

L is a number, not a list.
Maybe you mean :

```
import random

def compte(l,v):
    nbreOccurences = 0
    for i in l:
        if (i == v):
            nbreOccurences = nbreOccurences + 1
    return nbreOccurences

N = 100
        
l3 = []
for i in range(N):
    v = random.randrange(1,N+1)
    l3.append(v)

print(l3)
print(compte(range(13),3))
#### Here    ^^
```

Edit:
My answer is only correct if you want a list like this

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

In this case, it looks like @Shuvam Paul (below) is correct.
This shows how important naming variables with meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with the program is a typo. In the last line, instead of

```
print(compte(13,3))
```

I guess it will be ,

```
print(compte(l3,3))
```

In python , for loop iterates through a sequence only, like list, range, tuple, etc. That is why this problem was happening.

Therefore the code will stand as

```
import random
def compte(l,v):
    nbreOccurences = 0
    for i in l:
        if (i == v):
            nbreOccurences = nbreOccurences + 1
    return nbreOccurences

N = 100
            
l3 = []
for i in range(N):
    v = random.randrange(1,N+1)
    l3.append(v)

print(l3)
print(compte(l3,3))
```

Thank You.